# Color the background of app bar after adding border radius

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I have added a border radius for the app bar and the background of the app bar stays white color and want to add a color to the background of the border radius notches.

[image]

The code for the App bar

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        bottom: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    toolbarHeight: 100,
    title: Text(
      'Registration',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xff1F1F1F),
    // backgroundColor: #,
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `canvasColor` value:

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        canvasColor: Colors.transparent, // Change this
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
```

In this way you change the `Scaffold` default background color!

Answer (score 1):

create a custom AppBar as Follows and use it as your AppBar.

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatefulWidget with PreferredSizeWidget{
  @override
  _CustomAppBarState createState() => _CustomAppBarState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(double.infinity,100);
}

class _CustomAppBarState extends State<CustomAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
        child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                ))),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `extendBodyBehindAppBar:true`
under scaffold properties after setting `canvasColor:Colors.transparent` as suggested in the above answer